# How to solve by approximation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to solve an equation, but I do not want a value directly wanted to test several possibilities for the variable and thus find an appropriate value, as in an approximation by interaction. Would anyone know how to do this through software and what would be appropriate?

The equation model is:
800 cos x + 1200 sin x = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the identity $\sin(a+b) = \sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b$.

If you divide both sides of the equation by $\sqrt{1200^2+800^2}$, you get $\frac{800}{\sqrt{1200^2+800^2}} \cos x + \frac{1200}{\sqrt{1200^2+800^2}} \sin x =0$.

So, if we find an angle $a$ which satisfies $\sin a = \frac{800}{\sqrt{1200^2+800^2}}, \cos a = \frac{1200}{\sqrt{1200^2+800^2}}$ (which exists and is a unique angle in the first quadrant), we can rewrite the equation as $\sin (a + x) = 0$. Then, this is true when $a + x = \pi k$ or $ x = \pi k - a$ for integer $k$.

Comment: Okay, I even thought about doing that, but in my conception the sine would look like the cosine and vice versa. Why does it happen? @Batman

Comment: If you phase shift a sine by $\pi/2$ (90 degrees), you get a cosine. You could also use other trigonometric sum identities if you want. I just used the first one that came to mind.